# Using InitialContext for lookups on Liberty

Tags: ejb, websphere-liberty

I am working on migrating ear application from WebSphere 8.5 to WebSphere Liberty.

There are 2 EJB Applications A and B deployed on different systems.

In the code , whenever B has to talk with A, the steps were

a) Create InitialContext  and pass the EJB URL of A

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(env)
```

b) Use this InitialContext to then do JNDI lookup

To migrate this code to Liberty , I need to replace all JNDI lookups for EJB Interfaces with java namespace.

The migration tool also suggests using default InitialContext and not passing the INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY and PROVIDER_URL on Liberty

```
InitialContext  context = new InitialContext();
```

My question is how will this work in case of liberty for the above scenario where A and B are on remote systems ? 
Don't we require the EJB Url to be provided?

Another related question is whether this change is backward compatible with Websphere 8.5

Answer (score 0):

On Liberty, the `java:` namespace lookups are only available when looking up beans within the same server process. To lookup beans between server processes, you must use a `corbaname` lookup, where the `corbaname` would include the host and IP address of the target server.  Details about this may be found here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_ejb_remote.html

Also, an example of this may be found in the open-liberty source test project that explicitly tests different ways of looking up remote EJBs between processes:

https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/integration/dev/com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.remote_fat/fat/src/com/ibm/ws/ejbcontainer/remote/fat/tests/Server2ServerTests.java

And the actual servlet for that test (running on one of the two servers) is found here:

https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/integration/dev/com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.remote_fat/test-applications/RemoteClientWeb.war/src/com/ibm/ws/ejbcontainer/remote/client/web/RemoteTxAttrServlet.java

The test is using `localhost` since both servers are on the same system, so that would need to be replaced if they are on separate systems.

As for being portable with WebSphere traditional 8.5, the answer is no.  WebSphere traditional and Liberty would both support looking up remote interfaces in the `java:` name spaces for beans that are co-located in the same server process, however the behavior for looking up EJBs between processes is not compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you shed more details for EJB lookup between process in 8.5

Comment: Also which is the jar file which gives InitialContext in liberty?